# Geo Nodes curve to mesh node input multiple profile curves and multiple axis curves

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I have a sequence of nodes generating something similar to natural animal scaly skin like curves. I want these curves to serve as profile curves on a curve to mesh node or some other node that can generate mesh from these curves. I then have a mesh to points node that gives me a location at the approximate center of each profile curve. I then generate noisy curves at those center points. These noisy perpendicular curves I can then use to control their radius and form making the geometry generated from the profile curves long or short, smooth or noisy or even animated.

**The problem:** I want to have each profile curve go along each perpendicular noisy curve but the curve to mesh node treats all the profile curves as one single curve.  Is there a way to get each profile curve to "extrude" along each respective noisy curve perpendicular to it? Is this done by using the index node or ID node some how so that Blender knows which profile curve should be used for each perpendicular curve? How can I view each curve's index and then match it to each respective profile curve?

I tried using the separate geometry node in combination with the mesh island node. I thought that maybe this would make each profile curves become a separate individual meshes similar to when you have a collection of meshes and then choose separate children but that did not solve the problem.

I also tried converting the profile curves generated within geonodes to a mesh which I then separated by loose parts and placed within a collection. I then referenced the collection in the geonodes node tree and tried to use the separate children toggle in the collection info node to get each profile curve to "follow" each noisy curve. This also didn't work. The curve to mesh node ends up placing every separate profile curve on every noisy perpendicular curve or it seems to apply all of the collections contents at each noisy perpendicular curve. Is there some other approach that could achieve this sort of multiple profile curves for each perpendicular curve generated on the profile curve?

I tried approximating the final result I am attempting to setup with a sequence of nodes that combine the extrude mesh nodes and scale elements node but these do not generate geometry that has a noisy curve controlling them at their centers.

Here are some images illustrating the problem and attempts to build what I am trying to achieve. The first image shows the profile curves and the axis curves. The second image shows how every profile curve ends up at each axis curve. The third image shows the extrude mesh node and scale elements attempt. [image: round profiles and noisy axes][image: all profiles at each axis]
[image: extrude mesh attempt]

Comment: As far as I understand your question, what you want to do is unfortunately not currently possible with *Geometry Nodes*. `Curve to Mesh` can use several base curves, but it always extrudes all given profile curves along them and cannot process them differently.